# Is is possible to restrict sub directories in git repository running on apache server for certain users?

Tags: git, apache

There is a directory present in `Repo.git` named `Restrict` which I want to restrict for only admin user. I have added other users in `passwords.txt`. I can clone, commit and push to the repository but restrict access to that particular directory only to admin user.

This is my `httpd.conf` file:

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT "E:/srv/git"
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAlias /git/ "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/"

<Location "/git/">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "git"
    AuthUserFile E:/srv/auth_files/htpasswd.txt
    Require all denied
</Location>

<Location "/git/Repo.git/">
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "git test repository"
   AuthUserFile E:/srv/auth_files/passwords.txt
   Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: To have a clearer view of your goal : `Restrict` is a directory which is versioned within your `Repo.git`, right ? do you want to restrict the ability for non-admin users to push modifications on that directory ? do you want to forbid non-admin users to access this directory at all ?

Comment: I just want to forbid non-admin users. So that they wont have access to the `Restrict` directory.

Comment: I get that part, I don't get what "having/not having access to the Restrict directory" means. Will users interact with the content under `/git/Repo.git` as with a regular website (e.g : open `https://somedomain/Restrict/index.html` in their browser) ? or with git commands (e.g : `git clone somedomain:Repo.git`, `git pull / git push` ...) ?

Comment: They will be interacting with `git` commands.